# Is there a way to determine if a specific ajax is still running?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a few ajax running on my sites simultaneously with setInterval, and there are some with buttons,

so for example if I want to check if this was finished, before I run it again. cause everytime I scroll to the bottom I run this. What is the best way to know that It should not call this, will still it still running.

```
$.post(base_url+"index.php/contracts/getleftpanedocs", {},
                    function(data){

                        if(data.count > 0){
                            $("#spandocdisplaycount").html(data.count);
                            $("#divdocsdisplay").fadeIn("slow");
                        }else{
                            $("#spandocdisplaycount").html(data.count);
                            $("#divdocsdisplay").fadeOut("slow");
                        }
                  },"json");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably set a flag

```
loading = false;
if(!loading){
    loading = true;
    $.post(base_url+"index.php/contracts/getleftpanedocs", {},
        function(data){
           loading = false;
        }
}
```

something like that might work!

Comment: good idea, my idea was also make an input placeholder like input=1 if its still running, after callback set=0. but this works aswell, thanks. I just thought there was something like initializing an ajax to a variable and check if it still running using the variable. I could hope. Thanks.